# JPA2.2 + Subquery in SELECT for aggregation

Tags: sql, jpa, subquery

I'm working on a Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE app here, which brings Hibernate 5.4 + JPA 2.2.

The DB (shortened here):
Table 1 (sri):

```
id | fund_id
 1 | 20
 2 | 21
 3 | 22
```

Table 2 (ref):

```
  id | SECURITY_ID | FUND_PROPORTION | value
 100 |           1 |             0.2 |    70
 101 |           1 |             0.1 |    20
 102 |           1 |             0.5 |    60
 103 |           2 |             0.1 |    95
 104 |           2 |             0.1 |    23
 105 |           2 |             0.2 |    48
 106 |           3 |             0.4 |    65
 107 |           3 |             0.5 |    16
 108 |           3 |             0.2 |    32
```

...the actual values are not relevant - just to show how I get to those values.

I need to select values from the DB, but since it will be a large amount of results, I want the DB to do the calculation. That's why I have setup the following (shortened for this post here) query, which is working perfectly using plain SQL on the DB:

```
select 
    RATING, 
    SUM(FUND_PROPORTION),
    COUNT(FUND_PROPORTION)
from (
SELECT 
    ref.FUND_PROPORTION as FUND_PROPORTION ,  
    Case 
        when ref.value <= 100 AND ref.value > 90 then 'A' 
        when ref.value <= 90  AND ref.value > 75 then 'B' 
        when ref.value <= 75  AND ref.value > 50 then 'C' 
        when ref.value <= 50  AND ref.value > 25 then 'D' 
        when ref.value <= 25  AND ref.value > 10 then 'E' 
        when ref.value <= 10  then 'F' 
    END  AS RATING
FROM 
    table1 sri,
    table2 ref 
WHERE 
    sri.id = ref.SECURITY_ID 
    AND sri.fund_id = SOME ID
    GROUP BY FUND_PROPORTION, RATING
) as t1
group by RATING;
```

This returns the expected result:

```
RATING    SUM(FUND_PROPORTION)    COUNT(FUND_PROPORTION)
B         0.32                    1
C         0.28                    2
D         0.14                    5
E         0.03                    7
F         0.01                    8
```

...basically I need to have a Set of all FUND_PROPORTIONS and the RATING, which identifies the Set by giving it a name depending on it's value (as defined by the case statements). And then run a count/sum on that value and return it.

My problem: I cannot get it running in Java. Upon starting the Repository (JpaRepository or JpaCustomRepository), it complains about the "extra" "(" - which is the start for the subquery.
It seems like I cannot have a subquery in the SELECT part of the (main) query.

I've tried using native queries, but since we're using UUIDs, the driver tries to convert the values ti byte[] and fails (surprise, surprise). I've tried using the CriteriaAPI, but all examples I could find were about having the subquery in the WHERE part - which doesnt help me.

Sure, I can run run just the subquery and combine those values directly in Java, but that would mean to load a hell of data into the application - which is not what I want to happen (the results are from a tiny test DB, prod will look different quantity wise).

Now, I'm definitely willing to convert the query above to something else, e.g. joins. But I dont know, how to rewrite the query.

Any ideas? JPA (favourite), Criteria Api or a complete rewrite - everything making this thing up+running will do the job.

Thanks a lot.

kniffte

PS: I'll be in the mountains for the weekend, so no read/response from my side until Mo., Jul. 20th.

Comment: Use native query using @Query annotation in jpa repository and use interface/class based projection to map data

Comment: Thats what I tried, but starting the application fails with the cited error, that the "(" is invalid (because it is in the SELECT clause).

This seems to be the problem:

Quote from the JPA 2.2 specification, paragraph 4.6.16:

Subqueries may be used in the WHERE or HAVING clause.[66]

[66] Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered in a later release of this specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `nativeQuery` attribute in your annotation to use SQL

```java
@Query(
  value = "SELECT ...", 
  nativeQuery = true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)/[User - Upvote don't say Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4207306/user-upvote-dont-say-thanks) thanks for your support. Using the nativeQuery attribute was not the full answer but ultimately led me to the following solution:

Using nativeQuery = true does not work here, because you're basically losing Hibernate's support to define the response object (sorry, that wasn't part of my original request).

So now I've switched to a CustomRepository, adding a META-INF/orm.xml, defining the response object:

```
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">
<sql-result-set-mapping name="DistributionSearchResult">
    <constructor-result target-class="searchresult.DistributionSearchResult">
        <column name="RATING" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <column name="sum" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <column name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    </constructor-result>
</sql-result-set-mapping>
```

This definition is referenced when creating the nativeQuery as follows:

```
final String queryString = " SELECT " +
                "   RATING, " +
                "   SUM(FUND_PROPORTION) as sum, " +
                "   COUNT(FUND_PROPORTION) as count" +
                " FROM ( " +
                "   SELECT " +
                "       ref.fund_Proportion as FUND_PROPORTION, " +
                "       CASE " +
                "          when ref.value <= 100 AND ref.value > 90 then 'A' " +
                "          when ref.value <= 90  AND ref.value > 75 then 'B' " +
                "          when ref.value <= 75  AND ref.value > 50 then 'C' " +
                "          when ref.value <= 50  AND ref.value > 25 then 'D' " +
                "          when ref.value <= 25  AND ref.value > 10 then 'E' " +
                "          when ref.value <= 10  then 'F' " +
                "       END AS RATING " +
                "   FROM " +
                "       Security_Provider_Info spi, " +
                "       SCORE_ESG_REFINITIV_SEC_PROV ref " +
                "   WHERE " +
                "       sri.id = ref.SECURITY_ID " +
                "       AND sri.fund_id = :SOME_ID " +
                "   ) as t1 " +
                "   GROUP BY RATING ";

    /* set Parameter */
    final JpaQueryParameters parameters = new JpaQueryParameters();
    parameters.setParameter("SOME_ID", 123);

    /* see orm.xml for definition of DistributionSearchResult */
    final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, "DistributionSearchResult");
    parameters.addParameters(query);
```

This way, the results are grouped as requested and get pushed into my results object of type DistributionSearchResult.

Thank a lot :)

kniffte